# how to create a trigger on pl/sql when a function was used

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to learn PL/SQL and I'm stuck on how to create a trigger in PL/SQL when a function was used.

I'm trying to create to create a bank database so I create some table like

- `account` (numaccount, name, balance, num_card) - `num_card` is a foreign key
- `card` (num_card, max_delay, datecard)

I wrote some functions like

- a function that allows to withdraw money from bank branch
- a function that allows to withdraw money using card
- a trigger avoid withdrawing money when sold < amount

I want to create a trigger that avoid withdrawing money when datecard is < of today date!

This is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER expirationcarte
BEFORE UPDATE ON ACCOUNT
for each row
when ( new.DATECARD <  to_char(SYSDATE,'MM-DD-YYYY'))
BEGIN
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20012, 'la carte est expiré');
END;
/
```

I hope that u help me to learn how to create a trigger on pl/sql when a function was used or correct my code if that's possible

Comment: The trigger is on the table `account`. There is no `datecard` column in that table, so you can neither use the column `datecard` in the `WHEN` clause, nor can you access the column with `new.datecard`. In the trigger body (i.e. after `BEGIN`) , you must select the `card` belonging to the account instead in order to check its `datecard`.

Comment: On a side note: Your date comparison looks broken. You turn the current time (`SYSDATE`) into a string with `TO_CHAR` in order to campare it to the `datecard` column. *Is* that column a string column? If so, why? Don't store dates in strings, because a comparison would compare character by character making '12-12-1990' come after '11-11-2022', because '12' > '11'...

Comment: ... And if it is not a string column, then why do you compare it with a string? If it is a date column, then your DBMS will have to convert the string you just created from `SYSDATE` back to a date, where it will have to guess what part is the day and what part is the month, which depends on session settings and can utterly fail. If `datecard` is a date, as it should be, it should be `datecard < TRUNC(SYSDATE)`.

Comment: In your datamodel an account can have one or zero cards. You don't have to have a separate card table then. You can just make the card columns part of the account table. In that case you can have the trigger as you have written it (i.e. without having to select from another table), because the card's expiration date would be a column in the account table.